# As a learning data scientist, how do I understand which decoder to use?

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

I wanted to decode a string into its original data value, I'm not sure if I took the right steps, or if had used the wrong encoder, is there anyway to know which encoder to use when receiving decoded data?

```
import base64

x = 'f71069a5840386c6ece104de3f2bafc3ecb1ff37f1bc64d20a75a98715b17f17'
x = base64.b64decode(x)
print(x)

And I get the following: 
b'\x7f\xbdt\xeb\xd6\xb9\xf3\x8d7\xf3\xa7:y\xc7\xb5\xd3\x87^\xdd\xfd\x9bi\xf77y\xc6\xf5}\xfd\xfb\x7fV\xdc\xeb\x87v\xd1\xae\xf9k\xdf;\xd7\x96\xf5\xed\xfd{'

Where do I go from here?
```

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Comment: @jprebys I couldn't find the encoding that was used, it wasn't even given in the dataset provided

Answer (score 0):

I only see the digits 0-F, so I'm guessing you have base-16 not base-64. In this case you can just use `bytes.from_hex` to get your encoded string:

```
>>> x = 'f71069a5840386c6ece104de3f2bafc3ecb1ff37f1bc64d20a75a98715b17f17'
>>> bytes.fromhex(x)
b'\xf7\x10i\xa5\x84\x03\x86\xc6\xec\xe1\x04\xde?+\xaf\xc3\xec\xb1\xff7\xf1\xbcd\xd2\nu\xa9\x87\x15\xb1\x7f\x17'
```

Then you can decode it:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex(x).decode('utf-8', errors='replace')
'�\x10i��\x03����\x04�?+����7�d�\nu��\x15�\x7f\x17'
```

This doesn't look like UTF-8, so you'll need to replace that with whatever encoding was used.